# How can I use dropdowns and according to the dropdown I provide further details

Tags: python, jquery, html, angularjs, django

I used ng-if using radio buttons for yes or no selection and according to that provided the details but how can I use dropdowns and according to each deopdown selection I show the details like if I select Near Metro from the dropdown and I show the available places and when I select the place again from the dropdown I show the post office pincode

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ng-select or some event listener of javascript or jquery to get selected option value and use it in to proceed XHR request which gives you some response like place,s lantlng by which you show some points on map
if you are using dynamically generated dropdowns then you event-listeners must look like this in jquery

```
$(document).on('change', ".dropdownClass", function(){
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

else

```
$(".dropdownClass").on('change', function(){
    alert($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: That looks good - post a raw javascript (with out jQuery dependency) if you have it please.